# Contacts list -> "Connect to Outlook" - how to do it automatically?

Tags: 2013, outlook, contacts

My company has a contacts list on SharePoint and the requirement is that every user should have this list bound to outlook using standard "Connect to Outlook" functionality. The thing is they don't want everyone clicking the button. We need to provide some code or policy that somehow will bind the list to the outlook of every user in the company and I am looking for a way to do this. Where is this information stored?

Comment: May ask what you want to include in the contact list? The contact information of all the users of the company in one list or every contact the users have saved in Outlook to be shared among everyone? I'm asking because depending on that there can be different approaches and save much time and effort.

Comment: and what difference does it make? whatever contacts there are in the list, you can click on "Connect to Outlook" and have them viewed in your outlook. it's a standard sharepoint functionality. what I am looking for is how to connect those contacts to outlook WITHOUT user having to actually click "connect to outlook" button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms457051%28v=office.14%29.aspx

It can be included in Group Policy.